# Firebase signInwithRedirect() always goes to localhost instead of my App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

## CONTEXT

I'm working on Xcode (ios app) on an angularJS/ionic app, trying to use Firebase auth functions to login using Facebook.

To do that i'm using `signInWithRedirect()` and `getRedirectResult()`, it seems working until my code gets to `getRedirectResult()`, no errors shown but after access acceptance facebook is redirecting me on Safari to : **localhost:8080/var/containers/Bundle/Application/******/testApp.app/www/index.html#/login** instead of my app login page.

I setup the facebook app on the Developper Facebook website and set `https://testApp-32338.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler` into OAuth URI field.

---

## QUESTION

Is there a file in Xcode or somewhere (.XML or something), where i must write something about this redirect ? How to use Facebook to sign in my ionic/ios app ?

Here is my code :

```js
//********** EDIT 1 CODE **********//

function loginFacebook ()
{

var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('user_birthday, email, public_profile');


firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
// The only console.log() i can see in the console
console.log("0");

firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
console.log("1");
  if (result.credential) {
  console.log("2");
    var user = result.user;
    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    console.log("3");
  }
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;

});

}
```

---

## Edit 1 : (02/11/2018)

According to Firebase it seems to be a known problem, probably `wkwebview` is the main cause of this issue on an IOS/ionic app. In this link : https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/ ionic is speaking about "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing" (CORS), I'm really not familiar with this how could i "trap" the `signInWithRedirect()` result to change it to the required url ? Is this will fix my problem ? Is someone was already able to cope with this issue ?

---

## Edit 2 : (02/12/2018)

Trying a new method, using the `cordova-facebook4-plugin`, everything seems working, even the redirect part to my app and collecting datas (name, birthday, token...etc). The unknown part is how to link my results to the firebase auth provider ? In Firebase doc (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login) the method is to use `signInWithRedirect()` (see my first edit) or `signInWithPopUp()` (which is not working on phone app), there is a `signInWithCustomToken()`, but it doesn't work when i'm putting inside the Facebook given token. I also tried the `universal-links` method with unfortunately, same results. How do you guys would do this ? Is someone achieved the connexion between `cordova-facebook4-plugin` and Firebase ?

```js
//********** EDIT 2 CODE **********//

function loginFacebook()
{

var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
   console.log("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
  facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(function(token) {
    console.log("Token: " + token);

    // What to do with this Token to link to Firebase ???
  });
}

facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "user_birthday"], fbLoginSuccess,
  function (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
);

}
```

## Edit 3 : (02/14/2018) It's Working !!!

Finally is it working, thanks a lot to @mootrichard ! Here is my final working code :

```js
//********** EDIT 3 CODE FINAL **********//

// SIGNIN WITH FACEBOOK4
 
function loginFacebook()
{

var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
   console.log("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));

facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(function(token) {
   console.log("Token: " + token);
   connectProvider(token);
   
  });
}
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "user_birthday"], fbLoginSuccess,
  function (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
);
 
 
 
//CONNECT FACEBOOK TO THE FIREBASE PROVIDER

function connectProvider(access_token)
{
// Build Firebase credential with the Facebook access token.
var credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(access_token);

// Sign in with credential from the Google user.
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then(function(result) {

        var firstName = result.displayName.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        var lastName = result.displayName.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');
        
        console.log("The firstName is : ", JSON.stringify(firstName));
        console.log("The lastName is : ", JSON.stringify(lastName));

 $state.go("anOtherPage");

}).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;

});

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to look at one of Firebase's advanced guides. Since you already have your token, you can simply create the Facebook Credentials using:

```
// Build Firebase credential with the Facebook access token.
var credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(access_token);

// Sign in with credential from the Google user.
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
});
```

You can see their example at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#advanced-authenticate-with-firebase-in-nodejs.